# Windows Subsystem for Linux shows "no installed distributions" in run-as-Administrator PowerShell window

Tags: windows, bash, powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I have successfully installed WSL 2 and Ubuntu on my Windows machine.

My user account is not an administrator account.

If I start PowerShell and type `bash` it successfully starts bash, and `wsl --list` shows the Ubuntu distribution.

However if I run PowerShell as Administrator and type `bash` I get the following message:

> Windows Subsystem for Linux has no installed distributions.
> Distributions can be installed by visiting the Microsoft Store:
> https://aka.ms/wslstore

and the `wsl --list` command shows the same message.

Worst part is that I'm pretty sure this worked yesterday(!)

Comment: That has happened on my Windows Insider machine and I am still working on it. I will post an answer if I find anything.

Comment: I think this must be a bug in WSL. I removed the Linux App (Settings, Apps). I uninstalled the two WSL applications in Programs and Features. I turned off WSL in Windows Features. I restarted (a couple of times) and then tried to set this all up fresh and it still failed. It seems like a bug.

Comment: I have reported this though Windows Insider Feedback Hub. I have not solved the issue.

Comment: Is your user account an administrator? Or do you enter credentials to run a program/shell as admin?

Comment: @DanielB I have to enter credentials to become admin.

Comment: OK. Just to make extra sure: Those admin credentials are not the same you use for your regular account, right?

Comment: Right. I use a local admin account instead of my standard user account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have installed the linux distro using the ordinary user credentials.
If you start the powershell as normal user, you should see the correct info.
wsl state and installed apps seem to be specific to a user account.

Comment: With UAC however, it's the same account.

Comment: This sounds at least plausible, but is this something that has changed recently? Because I'm pretty sure that my admin account could start it before.

Comment: No, this has never changed. From the additional information you gave, this is the correct answer.

Comment: I see something similar. I logged into my non-admin user account, started PowerShell using "Run as administrator", ran wsl --install to create an Ubuntu distribution, then ran wsl --list in the very same run-as-administrator PowerShell window, and it says "... has no installed distributions." But running wsl --list in an ordinary PowerShell window does show the Ubuntu distribution. This is for both Windows 10 and Windows 11.

Comment: Tom's Hardware ( https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/get-started-windows-subsystem-for-linux-windows-11 ) says you need to run as administrator to install WSL. But the command wsl --install is supposedly for installing a distribution, not for installing WSL itself. Unless perhaps it does double duty by also installing WSL itself if it was not previously present. In any case, I think you'd need to run as administrator for options like wsl --update or --mount or --unmount, which affect all distributions or the kernel itself.