# Unable to install wsl distribution on Windows 2019

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed wsl on a Windows 2019 server via the following:

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
```

I restarted after this appeared to complete successfully.

The `wsl` command runs, but it doesn't seem fully functional as standard cli options are invalid.

```
wsl --install -d Ubuntu
Invalid command line option: --install
```

I have also tried manually downloading [distributions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual#downloading-distributions) via `curl.exe -L -o ubuntu-2004.appx https://aka.ms/wslubuntu2004` and installing it with `Add-AppxPackage` but running `wsl` still reports `Linux has no installed distributions.`

```
wsl
Windows Subsystem for Linux has no installed distributions.
Distributions can be installed by visiting the Microsoft Store:
https://aka.ms/wslstore
```

Any ideas on what I'm missing here? My ultimate goal here is simply to use rsync.

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/questions/1645715/windows-subsystem-for-linux-shows-no-installed-distributions-in-run-as-adminis) question suggests a possible reason.  Which suggests you need to provided additional information to properly diagnose your problem. In my experience it should be as easy as downloading and opening the AppxBundle for the WSL distribution you want to use. After you download the Appx file you are suppose to rename the file to .zip and then extract the archive.  Once extract you are suppose to run Add-AppxPackage on the .appx contained in the folder containing the files

Comment: if your *only* goal is rsync, I would suggest cygwin or learn robocopy which can accomplish the same thing.  Make no mistake, I am not saying Cygwin is great.. but it does indeed work and doesn't need WSL.  It will not have the overhead of WSL when not running.  Robocopy is indeed great (and built-in) but will require you to figure out the command line.

Comment: See this discussion for VBox: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=42791

Comment: You should install Ubuntu from the Windows Store.

Comment: I wanted to say the same thing as @harrymc but bailed out.  I wasn'[t sure if windows server supported it.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas: You're right - it's not available in Server, but there are workarounds, like download from the [Windows Store for business](https://businessstore.microsoft.com), [LTSC-Add-MicrosoftStore](https://github.com/kkkgo/LTSC-Add-MicrosoftStore) and probably others, but I haven't searched this out very seriously.